# Strange noises from AC/Dash board

Tags: ac, noise, coolant, radiator

So I'm hearing a creepy/whooshing sound coming from the dash board and the sound disappears when I turn off the AC.

Time to have the AC system replaced?  Recently had coolant replaced.

Anyone experienced this?  What was your experience?

Comment: What kind of car is it? Can you provide a capture of the noise?

Comment: Possibly low on refrigerant.  When you said coolant, did you mean refrigerant?

Comment: Does this describe your problem: http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/2322/12030

Answer (score 1):

This can be caused by being low on refrigerant.  Before the refrigerant enters the expansion valve next to the evaporator, the refrigerant needs to be in liquid form so that it can expand and perform its cooling function.  There needs to be a continuous supply of liquid from the condenser to ensure that refrigerant in gas form does not reach the evaporator.

When the refrigerant is under charged, the supply of liquid refrigerant can run out and you end up with gas entering the evaporator which you hear in the passenger compartment as a whooshing noise.